# "I'm in on it" Two prepositions in a row

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english

Is this sentence grammatically correct? What's the precise meaning?
"I'd like to make sure that *I'm in on it*."

Comment: A combination of two prepositions is very common: *up against, down by, off of, in amongst...*

Comment: @AndrewLeach first preposition (up, down, off, in, ...) is said to be considered as adverbs so two prepositions won't collide. Could it be true?

Comment: While it may be possible to classify some examples like that, I don't believe *in on it* can be. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In on* has a particular meaning, as evidenced by [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_on):

> Privy to (a secret).
>
> *Neither party leader will even let their own public in on that*

*In* restricts the application to a particular circle of people to which you have to be allowed entry; *on* refers to the subject (eg “give information on [something]”).

Combinations of two prepositions are not uncommon.

Comment: I'd say that 'be in on' and 'let [someone] in on' are the idioms, as per [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-in-on-something). I'd reckon 'She then became in on ...' is not available. 'Get in on ...' is a different idiom.

Answer (score -2):

Native speakers, I think, seem to simply say **I'm on it** (I ever watched a movie and one of the actor wanted to take responsibility to do something and he just said "I'm on it") . But as said @Andrew Leach that combining two prepositions is very common, so there's nothing to get confused about. Thank you!

Comment: *I’m on it* (action promised) and *I’m **in** on it* (status of involvement) don’t communicate the same idea.

Comment: Could you please explain that more? I think it's the same that the scene I watched the movie was the guy took care of something as their responsibility.

Comment: With *in*, it indicates participation. Without, they’re communicating action.